# Проблема отображения ошибки во время выполнения в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда вылетает ошибка во время выполнения, не важно какая именно, то отображение текста ошибки шакалит (текст немного размыт).
Кто-нибудь знает как это можно пофиксить ?
[image: Вывод ошибки и части программы]

Comment: только что проверил у себя. все в порядке и на маленьком экране ноута, и на большом экране. никаких искажений и размытий. однако у некоторых они есть. [вот как это можно устранить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343124/how-to-fix-blurry-vs2019)